# PHP - How can I go loop through and modify all the properties in an object?

Tags: php

```
class testClass {
protected $name;
protected $jobTitle;
protected $age;
public $otherStr;

public function setName($name) {code}
public function setJobTitle($title) {code}
public function setAge($age) {code}
public function setOtherStr($str) {code}


code
}

$test = new testClass();

//Loop through $test and modify all the string properties.
```

In the code above, I have a few properties that are protected and public, but mostly protected. I also have corresponding set methods.  How would I loop through all the properties of $test, or all the setmethods of $test, and if the property is a string, add "abc" to the end of it?

Comment: I think you can only do this via [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your setters are all called set[PropertyName] helps a lot. Something like this should work, but I'm currently unable to test it.

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    $funcName = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
    // add check for if property is a string, then...
    $funcName($value.'abc');
}
```

Hope that helps.
It's also a good idea to add explicit types to your properties.

I should also add that this is all good and well for code practice etc, but dynamically calling functions like this is generally not recommended.